# adding a list to another list

Tags: python, arrays, list

let's say there's a list,

---

```
list1= [[0, 4, 0, 0], [2, 0, 4, 0], [9, 8, 0, 0], [0, 2, 5, 0]]
```

and there's another list

---

```
list2= [a,b,c,d]
```

I've seen multiple questions that asks similar things but I couldn't get the proper answer for this question.

I want to make a list

---

```
list3= [[a,0,4,0,0],[b,2,0,4,0],[c,9,8,0,0],[d,0,2,5,0]]
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: `list3 = [[item2] + item1 for item1, item2 in zip(list1, list2)]`

Comment: what are the contents of list2? variables or characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the list and use the **[list.insert](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)** method to do what you want

```
list1= [[0, 4, 0, 0], [2, 0, 4, 0], [9, 8, 0, 0], [0, 2, 5, 0]]
list2= ["a","b","c","d"]

for i,v in enumerate(list2):
    list1[i].insert(0, v)

print list1
```

OR

```
result = []
for i,v in zip(list1, list2):
    result.append([v] + i)

print result
```

**Output**:

```
[['a', 0, 4, 0, 0], ['b', 2, 0, 4, 0], ['c', 9, 8, 0, 0], ['d', 0, 2, 5, 0]]
```

Comment: This alters the content of `list1`.

Answer (score 2):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) you can do:

```
result = [[i]+j for i, j in zip(list2, list1)]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> list1 = [[0, 4, 0, 0], [2, 0, 4, 0], [9, 8, 0, 0], [0, 2, 5, 0]]
>>> list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> result = [[i]+j for i, j in zip(list2, list1)]
>>> result
[['a', 0, 4, 0, 0], ['b', 2, 0, 4, 0], ['c', 9, 8, 0, 0], ['d', 0, 2, 5, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using an iterator + list comprehension:

```
>>> list1= [[0, 4, 0, 0], [2, 0, 4, 0], [9, 8, 0, 0], [0, 2, 5, 0]]
>>> list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> it = iter(list2)
>>> [[next(it)] + x for x in list1]
[['a', 0, 4, 0, 0], ['b', 2, 0, 4, 0], ['c', 9, 8, 0, 0], ['d', 0, 2, 5, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple [list-comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) -

```
In [1]: list1= [[0, 4, 0, 0], [2, 0, 4, 0], [9, 8, 0, 0], [0, 2, 5, 0]]

In [2]: list2= ["a","b","c","d"]

In [3]: [[list2[i]] + l1 for i, l1 in enumerate(list1)]  # Enumerate keeps track of the index, and also returns the current list element

Out[3]: [['a', 0, 4, 0, 0], ['b', 2, 0, 4, 0], ['c', 9, 8, 0, 0], ['d', 0, 2, 5, 0]]
```